# Hard drive clone using dd

Tags: linux, copy, clone, dd

I have two hard drives:

sda ST3500...blabla (doesn't matter) and sdb WD...blabla. I want to clone sda to sdb using dd.

I ran:

***dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=4096 conv=notrunc,noerror,sync***.

The problem is that dd also clones the label of sda (ST3500...) onto sdb. While booting SUSE from sdb it searches for WD... and fails to boot. Is there a way to clone a whole drive with dd and maintaining the target drive label/model information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The label is in the filesystem, not in the hard drive. It can be modified by filesystem tools such as `tune2fs -L` for ext2/3/4 filesystems. Simply modify the label after cloning.

Comment: I've found a tip saying to clone a disk keeping the target disk label, do: 


 ***dd if=original_disk of=target_disk skip=16 seek=16 bs=4096***

Will this work??

Answer (score 0):

you can change the label manually after cloning
I started a thread here for a debian system but I am sure it will also apply for SUSE

[debian forum link](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=121499)